# How to handle optional dynamic blocks in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I am trying to iterate in resource "launchdarkly_feature_flag" variables with dynamic block that might have optional nested objects - "variations" (could be 0 or 2+):

```
variable "feature_flags" {
  default = {
    flag_1 = {
      project_key = "project"
      key         = "number example"
      name        = "number example flag"
      description = "this is a multivariate flag with number variations."
      variation_type = "number"
      variations = {
        value = 100
      }
      variations = {
        value = 300
      }
      tags = ["example"]
    },
    flag_2 = {
      project_key = "project"
      key = "boolean example"
      name = "boolean example flag"
      description = "this is a boolean flag"
      variation_type = "boolean"
      tags = ["example2"]
    }
  }
}
```

Ive tried various scenarios of how to get all flag and always face different problems. Piece of code:

```
resource "launchdarkly_feature_flag" "ffs" {
  for_each = var.feature_flag_map
  project_key = each.value.project_key
  key  = each.value.key
  name = each.value.name
  description = each.value.description
  variation_type = each.value.variation_type
  
  # main problem here
  dynamic variations {
    for_each = lookup(each.value, "variations", {}) == {} ? {} : {
      content {
        value = each.value.variations.value
      }
    }
  }
  tags = each.value.tags
}
```

Could you please help with that? I am using 0.14v of Terraform

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first step would be to tell Terraform what type of value this variable expects. While it's often okay to omit an explicit type for a simple value and let Terraform infer it automatically from the `default`, when the data structure is this complex it's better to tell Terraform what you intended, because then you can avoid it "guessing" incorrectly and giving you confusing error messages as a result.

The following looks like a suitable type constraint for the default value you showed:

```
variable "feature_flags" {
  type = map(object({
    project_key    = string
    key            = string
    name           = string
    description    = string
    variation_type = string
    tags           = set(string)
    variations = list(object({
      value = string
    }))
  }))
}
```

With the type written out, Terraform will guarantee that any `var.feature_flags` value conforms to that type constraint, which means that you can then make your dynamic decisions based on whether the values are `null` or not:

```
resource "launchdarkly_feature_flag" "ffs" {
  for_each = var.feature_flags

  project_key    = each.value.project_key
  key            = each.value.key
  name           = each.value.name
  description    = each.value.description
  variation_type = each.value.variation_type
  tags           = each.value.tags

  dynamic "variations" {
    for_each = each.value.variations != null ? each.value.variations : []
    content {
      variations.value.value
    }
  }
}
```

---

As written above, Terraform will require that all values in `feature_flags` have all of the attributes defined, although the caller can set them to `null` to indicate that they are unset.

At the time of writing, in Terraform v0.14, there is [an experimental feature for marking attributes as optional](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html#experimental-optional-object-type-attributes) which seems like it would, once stabilized, be suitable for this use-case. Marking some or all of the attributes as `optional` would allow callers to omit them and thus cause Terraform to *automatically* set them to `null`, rather than the caller having to explicitly write out the `null` value themselves.

Hopefully that feature is stabilized in v0.15, at which point you could return to this and add the `optional` annotations to some attributes without changing anything else about the module.